# JQueryUI Datepicker: Hide "Today" button, but show "Done" button?

Tags: jquery-ui

The field I'm using the datepicker for is a date of birth, so the "today" button is obsolete. However, I'd like to give users the chance to hide the datepicker and type the date themselves. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put this in CSS:

```
#ui-datepicker-div button.ui-datepicker-current {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I found an almost-solution. If the dateRange is set such that "today" is not part of it, the "today" button is disabled (albeit *not* hidden).